# Drupal 7 using different themes on pages using omega and delta

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-theming, theming, delta

Can I use different sub themes on different pages. I have created two omega sub themes - Theme 1 (set as default) and  Theme 2. Can I now assign Theme 2, to a set pages using the delta and context module? I created a delta theme based on Theme 2, and a context based on the page names, but the pages display Theme 1.

Is the above possible, or am I limited to using variations of Theme 1?

Answer (score 1):

Use the module themekey http://drupal.org/project/themekey.

This should do what you need